# Is there a way to connect remotely to redis server using host-IP as host by different machine in Spring-Boot java application

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I want to connect my redis server remotely which is running in Ubuntu Machine through windows, But not able to connect and getting *Connection Refused Exception*. Application is build with spring boot. Please suggest me how I can do it.

Below is my sample code:

```
@Override
public void expireDevices() {
    JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), "IP address", 6379, Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
    try(Jedis jedis=pool.getResource()){
        // Doing Something
    }
    expireWithBackgroundTask();
}
```

Comment: Ubuntu machine through windows ?? (is that VM). Can you please post some of your code.

Comment: Hello. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide sample of the code that you have working till now.

Comment: sorry i am new to post question. I have added my code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If your Redis server is installed on Ubuntu then go to `/etc/redis/redis.conf` file and find attribute something like `bind 127.0.0.1`. You need to find public IP of your Redis server and replace it with `127.0.0.1` then restart the Redis.

**P.S.** If you open Redis on public IP then go through [Redis security risks](https://www.imperva.com/blog/new-research-shows-75-of-open-redis-servers-infected/)

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but even after restarting it is not going to public.  Below I changed in /etc/redis/redis.conf as I commented the default IP and kept mine IP like # bind 127.0.0.1
bind systemIP and changed protected-mode as no         but still i am not getting.

Comment: Are you able to ping to Ubuntu system from your Windows system ? If yes, then use that ping IP in redis.conf file. Also, you need to check firewall rules of Ubuntu system if 6379 port is enable for traffic ? Is this Ubuntu system on AWS ?

Comment: No this ubuntu system is not on AWS, it is a local System. I did what you told to change bind IP as my ubuntu system IP address,  but dont kniw how check 6379 port is enable for traffic or not .. Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Are you able to ping to your Ubuntu system from your windows system? Are they in the same network ?

Answer (score 0):

I second what Bhushan said, make sure that Redis is listening on a public IP. By default when you install it listens on localhost.